# Inherit comments from interface or base

Tags: .net, inheritance, comments

I noticed that in Java(doc) there exists something like @inheritDoc, so that comments from the nearest inheritable class are explicitly copied.

Does there exist something like this in .Net? I know this can be achieved with GhostDoc. The downside with GhostDoc is that changes to "base" comments are not manifested...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at Sandcastle? I believe it is now supported there.

http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/html/79897974-ffc9-4b84-91a5-e50c66a0221d.htm